# How can I get Mathematica to allow me to apply FindRoot to an expression that contains NIntegrate?

Tags: numerics

I am trying to run the following command in Mathematica:

```
FindRoot[NIntegrate[D[f[x], x] / Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, 0, 1}] - d, {a, 245}]
```

As you might expect, a is buried within f[x] and 245 is a reasonable initial guess at its value.  As you may also have guessed, the above integral is an expression for d in terms of a but I can't do the integral in closed form so I can't invert the expression to find a in terms of d.

So, I wish to numerically integrate my integral expression for d but that just give me the d that corresponds to a given value of a. I want to go the other direction, find the a value that corresponds to a given d.  That's what I'm using FindRoot for (kudos if you're staying with me so far, it's taken me days to get to this point).

So here's the problem: NIntegrate gets upset if anything in the integrand is an undefined variable so every variable in the above integrand is defined except a (because I don't know it yet).  However, FindRoot does know it.  What I mean is, FindRoot is presumably running in an iterative loop and in every iteration it is working with a guess at a so somewhere in the bowels of the code, a always has a definite value.  If I could somehow get NIntegrate to know this, I think I can get the above command to work (which would be a nice example of a powerful one line Mathematica operation).  Any tips or do you think I'm trying to do something impossible?

Thanks,

Dessie.

Comment: In general you can deal with the first problem by defining `int[a_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] = NIntegrate[...]`. This way `FindRoot` will evaluate its argument only when you supply numerical values.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe the solution is to insert the `FindRoot` option `Evaluated -> False`. In this way, you ensure that the integral is calculated before the `FindRoot[expr]` is evaluated. For example:

```
Block[{f, d = Pi},
 f[x_] := a^2 Sin[x];
 FindRoot[
  NIntegrate[D[f[x], x]/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, 0, 1}] - d, {a, 245},
  Evaluated -> False
 ]
]
(* -> {a -> 1.6166952922140634`} *)
```