# Numerical solution of a differential equation with NIntegrate coefficients

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a linear ODE with a variable coefficient which is given in terms of an integral I can only do numerically. That is, I have an equation of the form
$$
u'(t)=u(t)\int_0^t\sqrt{1+e^{-\tau^2}\sin(\tau)}d\tau,
$$
where the integrand could be pretty much any well-behaved function - but which in general will cause *Mathematica* to choke when given to `Integrate` and eventually say it can't do it.

I know that such a lack of an analytic handle on the coefficients in the equation essentially disqualifies me from an analytic solution of the equation. However, given that I am, or should be, perfectly able to numerically compute this coefficient, *Mathematica* ought to be able to numerically solve the equation.

My initial guess as to how to do this would be to simply indicate the integral should be done numerically:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t], t] == NIntegrate[
     Sqrt[1 + E^tt^2 Sin[tt^2]], {tt, 0, t}] u[t], u[0] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 1}]
```

but this simply outputs the error

`NIntegrate::nlim: tt = t is not a valid limit of integration. >>`.

I've also tried with plain `Integrate` and setting `GenerateConditions->False`, but none of them work and they also take a long time to return their errors, which I assume is because they're trying to symbolically solve the integral - and I specifically *don't* want that.

Can someone provide a way to make *Mathematica* understand it just needs to buckle down and calculate?

Comment: Define the integral as a separate function that can only evaluate for numerical arguments. For instance, `f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + Exp[-tt^2] Sin[tt^2]], {tt, 0, t}]; NDSolve[{u'[t] == f[t] u[t], u[0] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: A bracket was missing, edited.

Comment: @J.M. this question/issue really pops up every 2 weeks!

Comment: related (amongst many others) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13048/1089

Comment: @episanty Why do you want to use `tt` to describe `\[Tau]`. Hit escape key , t and then escape again to get tau. I see this `tt` a lot with matlab and C users alike but this isn't needed in mathematica.

Comment: @drN yeah, I use it in my code but I wasn't sure if it would display ok up here, and I guess it's best to keep code posted online as copiable as possible.

Comment: @chris, it's why I didn't want to post an answer. It's probably high time for a canonical question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
ClearAll[f];
f[t_Real] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + E^tt^2 Sin[tt^2]], {tt, 0, t}];
NDSolve[{D[u[t], t] \[Equal] f[t]* u[t], u[0] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 1}]
```

ie, define `f` such that it only evaluates its right hand side if its argument has head `Real`.

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to the answer of @acl, let's approach the ODE from mathematical side.

**Approach 1**
Let's denote $v(t) = \int_0^t f(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau$,where $f(\tau) = \sqrt{1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\tau^2} \sin(\tau)}$. Then clearly $v^\prime(t) = f(t)$ and $v(0) = 0$. You can thus rewrite you ODE as a system:
$$
    u^\prime(t) = v(t) u(t), \, v^\prime(t) = f(t),  \, u(0) = 1, \, v(0) = 0   \tag{1}
$$

**Approach 2**
Rewrite your equation as
$$
   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \log u(t) =  \frac{u^\prime(t)}{u(t)} = \int_0^t f(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau \tag{2}
$$
thus
$$
     u(t) = u(0) \exp\left( \int_0^t \left( \int_0^{s} f(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau\right) \mathrm{d} s\right) = u(0) \exp(w(t)) \tag{exact}
$$
where $w(t)$ satisfies $w^{\prime\prime}(t) = f(t)$ with initial conditions $w(0) = w^\prime(0) = 0$.

**Approach 3**
Alternatively, we could differentiate eq. (2) once more, and get
$$
     \frac{u^{\prime\prime}(t) u(t) - u^\prime(t) u^\prime(t)}{u(t)^2} = f(t),  \quad \text{or} \quad u^{\prime\prime}(t) u(t) = f(t) u(t)^2 + \left( u^\prime(t)\right)^2 \tag{3}
$$
with initial conditions $u^{\prime}(0) = 0$.

Let's compare three approaches using *Mathematica*:

[image]

---

Here are the inputs:

```
f[t_] := Sqrt[1 + Exp[-t^2] Sin[t]]

sol1 = NDSolve[{u'[t] == v[t] u[t], v'[t] == f[t], u[0] == 1, 
   v[0] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 4 Pi}]

sol2 = NDSolve[{u[t] u''[t] == f[t] u[t]^2 + u'[t]^2, u[0] == 1, 
   u'[0] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 4 Pi}]

solaux = NDSolve[{w''[t] == f[t], w[0] == 0, w'[0] == 0}, 
  w, {t, 0, 4 Pi}]

uexact[t_Real] := Exp[w[t] /. solaux]

LogPlot[{u[t] /. sol1, u[t] /. sol2, uexact[t]} // Evaluate, {t, 0, 
  4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Thickness[0.02]], 
   Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]], Directive[Yellow, Dashed]}]
```

Comment: I appreciate the approach, but in my particular case if it's a re-think on the maths side then it needs to go deeper (which, for efficiency reasons, you need to do anyway). My specific problem was getting it to evaluate when needed and not complain when not, which is solved by the `t_Real` trick.

Comment: @episanty Notice that approach 1 does exactly that, but avoid calling NIntegrate, thus achieving much better computational complexity.

Comment: @Sasha, do you have a timing for those three methods? I'm looking at a problem which contains three nasty integrals in my differential equation. Is there any way to know which method will be the fastest ?

Answer (score 2):

First solve this:

```
a = NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + E^tt^2 Sin[tt^2]], {tt, 0, 1}]
```

And then do this:

```
DSolve[{D[u[t], t] == a u[t], u[0] == 1}, u[t], t]
```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: the integral of the OP is indefinite: i.e. `a=a[t]=Integrate[Sqrt[1 + E^tt^2 Sin[tt^2]], {tt, 0, t}]`

Comment: @chris Oh crap! After doing this again, I came up with the same thing as @JM. But thanks for the `-1` `;-)`

Comment: sorry I wanted to remove the -1 but its not possible; I just wanted to warn readers this answer fell short of answering the OP's question.

Comment: @chris Thats alright! Theres more to life than forum points! `:P`