# Perform FindRoots on Function Evaluation Containing RootSearch

Tags: equation-solving, functions, numerics

I am using Ted Ersek's `RootSearch` function in Mathematica 9.0 (http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/) to create a function that I am using for graphing. Now, I'd like to use this function inside of a `FindRoot`s call to find specific solutions.

To begin, we have a function `f[t_, Rb_, N2_]`:

```
 f[t_, Rb_, N2_] =(4.22153*10^6 (45.5182 + 5.226*10^-6 N2^2 + Rb) (0.106 - 
                     0.106 E^(-9.43396 t) - Sin[120 \[Pi] t]/(120 \[Pi])))/N2^2
```

Then we define the `tsat2[Rb_, N2_]` function using Ersek's `RootSearch` function to find the `t` values where `f[t,Rb,N2] = 0.9`4 and return the minimum value.

```
tsat2[Rb_, N2_] := N[60*Min[t /. RootSearch[f[t, Rb, N2] - 0.94` == 0, {t, 0, 1}]]]
```

The above `RootSearch` function works great, it's this next step that's the trouble. We play a little trick to turn `tsat2` into a function of only `Rb` to satisfy some other conditions to obtain `tsat2[Rb,97.65*Rb]` Here's the problem: I need to find find `f[Rb,97.65*Rb]==1.5` using numerical methods. Before I go and write my own numerical solver, I'd like to see if I can get `FindRoots` to work:

```
FindRoots[tsat2[Rb, 97.65*Rb] - 1.5 == 0, {Rb, 10}]
```

However the problem is Mathematica doesn't even seem to evaluate this ambitious function call and only returns:

```
FindRoots[-1.5 + 60. (t /. $Failed) == 0, {Rb, 10}]
```

I suspect that somehow the `tsat2` function is not actually being evaluated inside the `FindRoot` statement, or more specifically, the `RootSearch` function isn't being passed the values from the higher `FindRoots` function call. I have tried this also using the `RootSearch` function (so we essentially have a nested `RootSearch`) and received the same error:

> In[203]:= RootSearch[tsat2[Rb, Rb 97.65`] - 1.5` == 0, {Rb, 10}]
>
> Out[203]= RootSearch[-1.5 + 60. (t /. $Failed) == 0, {Rb, 10}]

My question is: How do I get the `tsat2` function to act like any other function evaluation inside the `FindRoots` call?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this problem is solved using the solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/how-can-i-get-mathematica-to-allow-me-to-apply-findroot-to-an-expression-that-co).

The answer is that `FindRoots` needs to have the option `Evaluated->False` to ensure that the nested `RootSearch` is evaluated before the FindRoots[expr] takes place.