# Solve a function to find the optimum value of parameter in mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions, integral-equations

I have a complicated function as shown

[image: Function]

It doesn't have a standard integration as far as I know.

Now, numerical integration of the left hand side function over a set of points gives the right hand side value (sorry about the missing integration sign in the image).

I know the value of parameter $X0$ as constant and $x$ is the independent variable. I wish to extract parameter `alpha` which I know is a real number.

How shall I do that in *Mathematica*? I have tried `FindRoot` method,didn't work.

```
FindRoot[(NIntegrate[(Abs[
   0.5*Sqrt[Pi/(alpha)]*
    Exp[-((Pi*x)^2/(alpha))]*(1 - 
      Erf[(-32.3077)*Sqrt[(alpha)] + 
        I*Pi*x/Sqrt[(alpha)]])])^2, {x, 0.00081846, 0.000818573, 
 0.000818686, 0.0008188, 0.000818913, 0.000819026, 0.000819139, 
 0.000819253, 0.000819366, 0.000819479, 0.000819592, 0.000819706, 
 0.000819819, 0.000819932, 0.000820045, 0.000820159, 0.000820272, 
 0.000820385, 0.000820498, 0.000820612, 0.000820725, 0.000820838, 
 0.000820951, 0.000821065, 0.000821178, 0.000821291, 0.000821404, 
 0.000821518, 0.000821631, 0.000821744, 0.000821857, 0.000821971, 
 0.000822084, 0.000822197, 0.00082231, 0.000822424, 0.000822537, 
 0.00082265, 0.000822763, 0.000822877, 0.00082299, 0.000823103, 
 0.000823216, 0.00082333, 0.000823443, 0.000823556, 0.000823669, 
 0.000823783, 0.000823896, 0.000824009, 0.000824122, 0.000824236, 
 0.000824349, 0.000824462, 0.000824575, 0.000824689, 0.000824802, 
 0.000824915, 0.000825028}]) == 0.0139828, {alpha, 0.001}]
```

[image: The code with error]

$X0$ for a particular case is -32.3077, becomes $0$ for particular $x$ and varies upto +30.3699 for different cases.

'alpha' for that particular X0 should come around 0.03 and thus alpha varies with $X0$

Comment: 1) Add code to your question rather than an image. 2) Show us what you have tried so far, and why it didn't work. 3) Add the values of the constants in your expression. 4) what are the limits of integration?

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for the reply, I have added my code sample kindly help me out. I hope I have addressed your requirements.

Comment: Links to answers for this issue are found in [the section on `NumericQ`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) of this Q&A: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: @Jens  I thought of using `f[alpha_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := Abs[0.5*Sqrt[Pi/alpha]*Exp[-(Pi*x)^2/alpha]*(1 - Erf[-32.3077*Sqrt[alpha] + I*Pi*x/Sqrt[alpha]])]^2` followed by `FindRoot[NIntegrate[f[alpha, x], ...` in my answer, but the error message persisted.  Of course, even the code in the question gives the correct answer despite the error message.

Comment: @bbgodfrey `FindRoot[eq[alpha],{alpha,0.001}]` works if I define `eq[alpha_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[Abs[0.5 Sqrt[\[Pi]/alpha] Exp[-((\[Pi] x)^2/alpha)] (1-Erf[-32.3077 Sqrt[alpha]+(I \[Pi] x)/Sqrt[alpha]])]^2,{x,..]-0.0139828`... but I upvoted your answer, too.

Comment: I found another possible duplicate (this type of issue is so common that answers are scattered throughout this site): [How can I get Mathematica to allow me to apply FindRoot to an expression that contains NIntegrate?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11297/245). I think it's better not to add to this proliferation, so I still propose to close this question.

Comment: @Jens  Yes, you are right on both counts.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the option, `Evaluated -> False` tells `FindRoot` not to evaluate the function (`NIntegrate` in this case) before inserting `alpha`.

```
FindRoot[NIntegrate[Abs[0.5*Sqrt[Pi/alpha]*Exp[-(Pi*x)^2/alpha]*(1 - 
    Erf[-32.3077*Sqrt[alpha] + I*Pi*x/Sqrt[alpha]])]^2,
    {x, 0.00081846, 0.000818573, 
     0.000818686, 0.0008188, 0.000818913, 0.000819026, 0.000819139, 
     0.000819253, 0.000819366, 0.000819479, 0.000819592, 0.000819706, 
     0.000819819, 0.000819932, 0.000820045, 0.000820159, 0.000820272, 
     0.000820385, 0.000820498, 0.000820612, 0.000820725, 0.000820838, 
     0.000820951, 0.000821065, 0.000821178, 0.000821291, 0.000821404, 
     0.000821518, 0.000821631, 0.000821744, 0.000821857, 0.000821971, 
     0.000822084, 0.000822197, 0.00082231, 0.000822424, 0.000822537, 
     0.00082265, 0.000822763, 0.000822877, 0.00082299, 0.000823103, 
     0.000823216, 0.00082333, 0.000823443, 0.000823556, 0.000823669, 
     0.000823783, 0.000823896, 0.000824009, 0.000824122, 0.000824236, 
     0.000824349, 0.000824462, 0.000824575, 0.000824689, 0.000824802, 
     0.000824915, 0.000825028}] == 0.0139828, {alpha, 0.001}, 
    Evaluated -> False]

(* {alpha -> 0.00132634} *)
```

Incidentally, the expression in the question contains many unnecessary pairs of parentheses.  Although not harmful, they make the expression longer and, for me, more difficult to read.